# why is average of a random subset the same of the initial set

Tags: probability, expected-value, average

This feels like a really simple question, plus it looks very intuitive, but I can't find a formal proof or anything that proves it.

I have an initial set X with n values. I extract Y, a random subset of X of size l.

Why is it that the Expected average of Y is equal to the average of X?

Comment: Because each element in either the subset, or in the entire set, has the same expected value and expectation is linear.

Comment: @lulu I don't think we're assuming that the elements themselves are random. But I agree that we can use linearity of expectation to solve this.

Comment: @DavidK  Not sure what you mean.  If the subset is chosen non-randomly then all bets are off.  You'd need to study the selection rules.

Comment: @lulu I meant the original set. For example, we could decide beforehand that $x_k = k$ for $1 \leq k \leq \lvert X\rvert.$ While not explicitly stated in the problem, I think we're expected to assume that each subset of the desired size is equally like to be selected, otherwise, as you say, it isn't a well defined problem.

Comment: @lulu As I thought, the answer is as simple as the question. If you'll post your comment as an answer I'm going to mark it as accepted